# Stacking multiple plots on a 2Y axis

Tags: matplotlib, plot, spyder

I am trying to plot multiple plots in a 2Y plot.

I have the following code:

- Has a list of files to get some data;
- Gets the x and y components of data to plot in y-axis 1 and y-axis 2;
- Plots data.

When the loop iterates, it plots on different figures. I would like to get all the plots in the same figure.
Can anyone give me some help on this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
file=[list of paths]

for i in files:

 # Loads Data from an excel file
    data = pd.read_excel(files[i],sheet_name='Results',dtype=float)

 # Gets x and y data from the loaded files
    x=data.iloc[:,-3]
    y1=data.iloc[:,-2]
    y12=data.iloc[:,-1]
    y2=data.iloc[:,3]

    fig1=plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)    
    ax1.set_xlabel=('x')
    ax1.set_ylabel=('y')

    ax1.plot(x,y1)
    ax1.semilogy(x,y12)

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis
    ax2.plot(x,y2)

    fig1.tight_layout()  

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate the figure outside the loop, and then add the subplots while iterating. In this way you will have a single figure and all the plots inside it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
files=[list of paths]

fig1=plt.figure()

for i in files:

 # Loads Data from an excel file
    data = pd.read_excel(files[i],sheet_name='Results',dtype=float)

 # Gets x and y data from the loaded files
    x=data.iloc[:,-3]
    y1=data.iloc[:,-2]
    y12=data.iloc[:,-1]
    y2=data.iloc[:,3]

    ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)    
    ax1.set_xlabel=('x')
    ax1.set_ylabel=('y')

    ax1.plot(x,y1)
    ax1.semilogy(x,y12)

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis
    ax2.plot(x,y2)

    fig1.tight_layout()  

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!